# Classification of flat Riemannian three manifold

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, flatness

[By a theorem of L. Bieberbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_manifold) we know that that every closed flat Riemannian manifold is a quotient of a torus via action of a  finite group $\Gamma$. In this question we are interested in the particular case of $3$ dimensional flat riemannian manifolds. 
So we assume that $(M,g)$ is a flat Riemannian $3$-manifold. then by above theorem we know that $(M,g)\cong T^3/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a finite group.

**Questions**

- Is there a  complete classification of  all  finite group actions on flat $3$-torus which resulting quotion space would be a an orientable manifold with vanishing first Betti number or first integral homology?
- According to  Wikipedia  Wiki(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_manifold), there is a  complete list of all  6 orientable and 4 non-orientable  flat compact  manifolds. This list consists of  all Seifert fiber spaces. Does the link of wikipedia actually means that all  orientable Seifert Hyper spaces of dimension $4$ and $6$ have been classified?
  Any reference is welcome!

Comment: Classification up to what? isometry? affine?

Comment: A classification can be found in "Spaces of Constant Curvature" by Joseph Wolf. In particular, there is a unique orientable flat 3-manifold with zero first Betti number, the so called  Hantzsche–Wendt manifold.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thanks a lot. Do you know how it is related to Seifert manifold?

Comment: Seifert manifold structures on flat 3-manifolds are described in P.Scott's "The geometries of 3-manifolds", see pp/443-448 in https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Teach/2012_MA4J2/geometry.pdf.

Comment: For an exposition of these manifolds, check out this paper by Colin Adams and Joey Shapiro: The Shape of the Universe: Ten Possibilities - American Scientist

https://www.americanscientist.org/sites/...org/files/200522415348_306.pdf

Comment: The OP doesn't answer my request, while several people seem to find the question clear and hence hopefully have a clear meaning in mind (hopefully, the same), about what the classification is up to. My guess is that it considers flat 3-folds up to diffeomorphism (or equivalently homeomorphism), or equivalently, I guess, up to isomorphism of the fundamental group; I guess it also means up to conjugation in the affine group. It's certainly not up to isometry or homothety since in this case there are continuum many possibilities (e.g. tori).

Comment: I would also guess that "of dimension 4 and 6" is a typo. But it does not make the question any clearer.

Comment: @YCor: for euclidean 3-manifolds homemorphism, diffeomorphism and affine-linear homeomorphism are all equivalent.  As you say, the isometry question is significantly more subtle as these manifolds have volumes and shortest closed geodesics, etc.

Comment: @YCor: an isometric classification (i.e. the moduli space) of compact flat manifolds is described in  https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08431. In particular, any compact flat manifold  of dimension $\ge 2$ has a non-homothetic deformation through flat metrics.